# zuul multiple urls one path

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

Hi I have a route that can have multiple servers...

I have tried the following to no luck:

```
zuul.routes.example.path=/example/**
zuul.routes.example.serviceId=example
example.ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
example.ribbon.eureka.listOfServers=http://127.0.0.1/metrics,http://127.0.0.1/info
```

This just returns the following error:

> Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: example

I am using eureka for most routes, but for this one in particular I cannot use eureka.

Is it possible to get zuul to loadbalance between the two urls?

**Solved**

The answer below solves this issue with config, however I would mention I was using spring-boot-starter-parent, I also had to upgrade the dependency management to Camden.SR7

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<!--         <version>Brixton.SR5</version> -->
        <version>Camden.SR7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try the following properties instead of yours.

```
zuul.routes.example.path=/example/**
zuul.routes.example.serviceId=example
example.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
example.ribbon.listOfServers=http://127.0.0.1/metrics,http://127.0.0.1/info
```

Comment: Does this mean I can't use eureka for some and local config for others?
 - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/564

Comment: The above linked issue is very old question.  The above properties works for me. Only example service will work on local config and others will work on eureka.

Comment: hum, if I add ribbon.eureka.enabled=false it works though :/ do you have eureka on your classpath?

Comment: Sure. I have eureka. Which version of spring cloud are you using ?

Comment: 1.2.3.RELEASE I think will try a newer version

Comment: 1.1.5.RELEASE is the version, I am using spring-cloud-starter-zuul 1.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: Probably this feature - specifying NXXXXXClassname with properties - was added from spring-cloud-netflix 1.2.0. Please refer to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/927